# Translating a diagram chase into an element-free proof

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

One part of the four lemma says that:

> Consider the following diagram with exact rows in an abelian category $\mathsf{A}$:
> [image]
>
> If $m$ and $p$ are monomorphisms and $l$ is an epimorphism, then $n$ is a monomorphism.

We can very simply prove this by diagram chasing. I'll copy a proof below:

- Let $c \in C$ be such that $n(c) = 0$.
- $t(n(c))$ is then $0$.
- By commutativity, $p(h(c)) = 0$.
- Since $p$ is injective, $h(c) = 0$.
- By exactness, there is an element $b$ of $B$ such that $g(b) = c$.
- By commutativity, $s(m(b)) = n(g(b)) = n(c) = 0$.
- By exactness, there is then an element $a′$ of $A′$ such that $r(a′) = m(b)$.
- Since $l$ is surjective, there is $a$ in $A$ such that $l(a) = a′$.
- By commutativity, $m(f(a)) = r(l(a)) = m(b)$.
- Since $m$ is injective, $f(a) = b$.
- So $c = g(f(a))$.
- Since the composition of $g$ and $f$ is trivial, $c = 0$.

**I want to "translate" this proof into an element-free proof using universal properties.**

The beginning is simple. The composition $\ker n\to C\to C'\to D'$ is zero. By commutativity of the diagram, so is $\ker n\to C\to D\to D'$. But $p:D\to D'$ is monic, so we conclude that $\ker n\to C\to D$ is zero. This seems to be the first 4 steps in the proof above.

However I don't know how to continue. (If an element-free proof of this cannot simply be a translation of the diagram chase, I would still want to learn it.)

Comment: You don't need to start with $\ker n\to C$. To see that $C\xrightarrow n C'$ is mono, all you need to check is that any morphism $c:X\to C$ with $(X\xrightarrow c C\xrightarrow n C')=0$ is actually the zero morphism $0:X\to C$. The proof is exactly the same and it is lighter in notation.

Comment: A proof that only relies on the snake lemma is given [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05QA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\img{\mathrm{img}}$

It's a bit more involved. I needed the fact that, in an Abelian category, [pullbacks preserve epimorphisms](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08N4). If you are willing to keep going, the next step would be to see that, since $(\ker n\to C \xrightarrow h D)=0$, then $\ker n\to C$ factors through $\ker h\to C$, which by exactness is the same as $\img g\to C$. Then take the pullback of $\ker n\to\img g$ and $B\to\img g$... this is the 5th step in your proof. Can you continue?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the answer and the comment by Jackozee Hakkiuz, I did the following proof. (The notations are not exactly the same, but it should be clear. Also the proposition 1.3.3 is simply the fact that the pullback of an epimorphism is epic.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope that this may be useful to someone :)

Comment: Yay, that's exactly the proof I came up with, too. Glad to see it went well. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your original proof works just fine in any Abelian category if you switch notation slightly. In categories for the working mathematician, Mac Lane lays out 6 rules for diagram chasing in any Abelian category which can be rigorously shown using universal properties alone.

The idea is to consider "members" of an object; $x\in_m A$ is an equivalence class of arrows with target $A$, where $x:X\to A$ is equivalent to $y:Y\to A$ if there exists $Z$ and epimorphisms $u:Z\to X,v:Z\to Y$ such that $yv=xu$. This can be shown to be a genuine equivalence relation that is preserved by composition and from there you can go through more or less the same motions... you can add and subtract members in a well-defined way, and you can do things like: if $fx\equiv0$ then $x\equiv(\ker f)y$ for some $y\in_m\mathrm{Ke}(f)$, etc.

I give an example of the careful use of these rules [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4676901). Seriously, your original proof *is* rigorous if you switch to members (a.k.a "pseudoelements") :) the universal properties are just hiding in a sneaky way. The universal properties and the property "pullback of epi is epi" for Abelian categories are used to justify these rules, but once you've established them you can do all of this. What's more, you can explicitly unwind a member-based proof into a purely diagrammatic proof by going through the proofs of each rule. You'd get something similar to the purely diagrammatic proof you posted for yourself.

The one drawback of this is that, while it's brilliant for checking things where the arrows are already given to you, I don't think you can use it to actually define arrows in the way you can use elements to define functions. But at least we know how to convert the member-based yoga into specific diagrams, so, you can always do this if you really need to.