# Show that $\overline\beta$ is epimorphism without diagram chasing

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, epimorphisms

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abeilan category. Consider the following exact, commutative diagram in $\mathcal{A}$
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}\ker a@>{\overline\alpha}>> \ker b@>{\overline \beta}>>\ker c\\
@V{k_a}VV @V{k_b}VV @V{k_c}VV\\
A @>{\alpha}>>B@>{\beta}>>C@>>>0\\
@V{a}VV @V{b}VV @V{c}VV\\
A' @>{\alpha'}>>B'@>{\beta'}>>C'@>>>0\\
@VVV\\
0
\end{CD}$$, where the first row is kernel of $a,b,c$, respectively.
I want to show that $\overline \beta$ is an epimorphism.

If we can use element to do the diagram chasing, then the proof is so elementary.

But, we now live in the world of Abelian category. By definition, let $\ker\mathop\rightarrow\limits^{f} X$ be a morphism such that $f\overline \beta=0$. We want to show $f=0$. My main problem is that $f$ is a morphism that leaves from the diagram at the location $\ker c$. So, I don't know how to use the comutativity of the diagram to argue the epiness of $\overline\beta$.

Does there any command, idea or detailed proof of the proposition on some references? Thanks in advance for your kindly help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\coker}{\operatorname{coker}}$We can use the *generalised* diagram chase (see MacLane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician* for a proof of the following rules, or have a go yourself):

> [image: Generalised diagram chasing]

Here, a statement like "$x\in_m a$" just means ("$m$" for "member"), there is some object $X$ and some arrow $x:X\to a$. If $x,y\in_m a$ are equivalent ($x\equiv y$) then that means to say: "there are epimorphisms $u,v$ with $xu=yv$". Of course, $\equiv$ is an true equivalence relation on "members" of any object.

It will be possibly to prove this directly, but the rules of the generalised diagram chase make it a hellavalot easier!

Ok, so let $z\in_m\ker c$ be arbitrary. I know that $k_cz\in_m C$, and I know by exactness of the middle row that $\beta$ is epic - hence, by rule $\rm(iii)$, there is some $y'\in_m B$ with $\beta y'\equiv k_c z$. Now, $c(k_c z)\equiv 0$ of course and $c(k_c z)\equiv c\beta y'=\beta'by'$ so that by rule $\rm(v)$ and exactness of the last row, there is $x\in_m A'$ with $\alpha'x\equiv by'$.

By rule $\rm(iii)$ and exactness of the leftmost column I know $a$ is epic and that there is $x'\in_m A$ with $ax'\equiv x$, that is, there is $x'\in_m A$ with $b\alpha x'=\alpha'ax'\equiv by'$

By rule $\rm(vi)$ there is $z'\in_m B$ with $bz'\equiv 0$ and the property $f\alpha x'\equiv0\implies fy'\equiv fz'$ for any arrow $f$ with domain $B$.

By rule $\rm(v)$ (or by very definition of "kernel") there is $y\in_m\ker b$ with $k_by\equiv z'$.

Then, $k_c\overline{\beta}y=\beta k_by\equiv\beta z'$. But $\beta\alpha x'=(\beta\alpha)x'\equiv0$ and so $\beta y'\equiv\beta z'$ by definition of $z'$. But, $\beta y'\equiv k_c z$! Therefore $k_c\overline{\beta}y\equiv\beta z'\equiv\beta y'\equiv k_c z$ and by rule $\rm(ii)$, $k_c$ being monic as all kernel arrows are, we have $\overline{\beta}y\equiv z$.

Since $z\in_m\ker c$ was arbitrary and such $y\in_m\ker b$ always exists with $\overline{\beta}y\equiv z$, by rule $\rm(iii)$ we have that $\overline{\beta}$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for your excellent answer!

Comment: @梁孟豪 You're welcome. For another reference on Abelian categories, see [Freyd](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/freydab.pdf)

Comment: Hello! I'm so wondering which subject of math is your major! Let me introduce myself first. I'm studying in a math doctor program in Taiwan. I'm major at harmonic analysis, especially in Fourier integral operators. Let me thank you again for your kindly reply!

Comment: @梁孟豪 Well, I don't yet major in anything in particular. I am just a high school student (and have had to take a break for the last few, and upcoming few more, months due to high school). I think at university I might like to "specialise" in algebraic topology or things like ergodic theory and probability theory, but it's too early to say.

Comment: I am curious, do Abelian categories come up in your harmonic analysis studies? Or are you looking at them as a separate thing

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at the abelian category as separate thing. I want to learn some homological algebra techniques to help me understand more about sheaf cohomology and use it to solve partial differential equations, especially in several complex variables.

Comment: Wow, cohomology can solve PDEs? Insane. @梁孟豪

Comment: FShrike, can I ask you for one more question? What is your point on the MacLane pseudo-element in Abelian category?

Comment: I think the key point is that every arrow has epi-mono factorization. Hence, after module epi part, it will leave the mono part of an arrow. But, what's the relationship between mono and elements? Even though in the category of sets, it's not clear for me.

Comment: @梁孟豪 Have you heard of ‘subobjects’ in category theory? $X\subset Y$ often means, “there is a monomorphism $X\to Y$”. In $\mathsf{Set}$, that concept essentially captures the idea of subset. Also, there, we have a correspondence between elements of a set $X$ and arrows $1\to X$. So this ‘member’ or ‘generalised element’ is just what you get when you replace $1$ by an arbitrary object. It’s useful here because it allows for a human-friendly notion of diagram chase

Comment: I'm still confused with this. In the category of sets, once I replace $1\rightarrow X$ by $\bullet\rightarrow X$, where $\bullet$ may not be a singleton. In this case, which element in $X$ is corresponded by the arrow $\bullet\rightarrow X$?

Comment: @梁孟豪 So this is *generalised*, now. Arrows $\bullet\to X$ don't correspond to literal elements, but they are called generalised elements or members because sometimes you can do manipulations with them "as if" they were genuine elements. Just like in the above diagram chase: "let $z\in_m\ker c$ be arbitrary" is taking any old arrow $z:\bullet\to\ker c$ and then the proof does a bunch of manipulations on that arrow, behind the scenes, but the concept of "member" makes this more human-friendly because treating things like elements and "doing things" to elements is something we are used to