# Generalizing theorem over $\mathbf{R}$-$\mathbf{mod}$ to abelian category $\mathbf{A}$

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I've been working through Weibel's *Introduction to Homological Algebra* and have a question concerning a proof of Theorem 1.3.1:

> Given a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow A_*\rightarrow B_*\rightarrow C_*\rightarrow 0$ (where each member of the sequence is a chain complex over an abelian category $\mathbf{A}$), there exist natural maps $\partial:H_n(C)\rightarrow H_{n-1}(A)$ such that the following is a long exact sequence:
> $$ ...\rightarrow H_{n+1}(C)\rightarrow H_n (A)\rightarrow H_n(B)\rightarrow H_n(C)\rightarrow H_{n-1}(A)\rightarrow ... $$

Now, I understand the proof of the this theorem when working over the category $\mathbf{R}$-$\mathbf{mod}$, where I can use the algebraic definition of the kernel and image. However, I am struggling to understand why the following statement holds for arbitrary abelian categories $\mathbf{A}$:

> The kernel of $d:A_n\hspace{.5mm}/ \hspace{.5mm}dA_{n+1}\rightarrow Z_{n-1}(A)$ is $H_n(A)$.

Where I assume this differential operator is the one induced by the cokernel of the monomorphism $d A_{n+1}\rightarrow A_n$.

I have spent quite a bit of time attempting to show this is the case in a general categorical sense (where kernels and images are not expressed as sets but as morphisms), however, I have been unable to show that $\ker d$ satisfies the same universal property that would hold for the cokernel of the monomorphism $i:B_n (C)\rightarrow Z_n (C)$.

Is this approach of showing $\ker d$ satisfies the universal property described above a correct way to prove this statement in the general case of chain complexes over $\mathbf{A}$? And in either case, is there an easier way to prove the statement, perhaps with the Freyd-Mitchell Embedding Theorem?

Comment: Are you already allowed to use the Snake Lemma at this point in Weibel's book?

Comment: Yes, that was proved already

Answer (score 2):

Using the Freyd-Mitchell theorem is not an easy way and it’s also a dangerous way unless you’re really sure you know what you’re doing; there are many statements false for general Abelian categories that are true for module categories.

Instead I recommend Mac Lane’s principle of the generalised diagram chase. Here’s an [introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4676901).

Firstly we need to check the induced map $H_nA\to A_n/dA_{n+1}$ is a monomorphism. Let $z\in_m H_nA$ be killed by this map and represent it by $x\in_m Z_nA$. The death of $z$ implies $\iota x\in_m A_n$ is killed by the quotient $A_n\twoheadrightarrow dA_{n+1}$, and the kernel of this map is $\iota’:dA_{n+1}\hookrightarrow A_n$. Therefore $\iota x\equiv\iota’y$ for some $y\in_m dA_{n+1}$. But then, for $\iota’’:dA_{n+1}\hookrightarrow Z_nA$, $\iota x\equiv\iota(\iota’’y)$ so $x\equiv\iota’’y$ since $\iota$ is monic and by definition of homology that implies $z\equiv0$. You can make that check faster when you’re used to it.

Now we need to check that, if $x\in_m A_n/dA_{n+1}$ is killed by $d$ then $x$ comes from $H_nA\hookrightarrow A_n/dA_{n+1}$. Represent $x$ by $y\in_m A_n$; we know $dy\equiv0$, so $y$ factors as $\iota z\equiv y$ for some cycle $z\in_m Z_nA$. Then $[z]\in_m H_nA$ maps to $x$, so we are done.

So you can see the proof is more or less the proof you’d use for modules. You just need to be sure you know where you’re using certain categorical properties e.g. $Z_n A\to A_n$ being a monomorphism.

Comment: Do you have a simple example at hand of a statement that follows for Mod but not for an abelian category?

Comment: @Julián For example all the AB3,AB4,AB5 axioms and their duals. Then from there certain things such as “generalised elements of a direct sum are determined by their components” don’t work. This matters for some situations in homological algebra. One very relevant one is the Mittag-Leffler criterion for vanishing of the first derived inverse limit functor; this requires AB4* as an axiom but if you’re not careful you could easily be fooled into thinking that it’s easily proven with generalised elements/module embedding.

Comment: Why do we need to check that the map $H_n(A)\rightarrow A_n\hspace{.5mm}/ \hspace{.5mm}dA_{n+1}$ is a monomorphism, since doesn’t the second part (proving this map is $\ker d$) automatically prove the monic nature?

Comment: @moboDawn_φ But the second part *doesn't*, on its own, prove this map is $\ker d$. It only proves this map has image equal to $\ker d$. There are two parts of the universal property: (1) any map killed by $d$ must factor through $\ker$ (which I verify in the second part) (2) this factorisation is **unique** (equivalently, $\ker$ is monic) and this I have to verify separately; I do this in the first part

Comment: Ah I see thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the snake lemma, there is another way to show this. I will write $B_n(A)$ for $dA_{n+1}$. Since $Z_{n-1}(A)\hookrightarrow A_{n-1}$ is a monomorphism, and $A_n\to A_{n-1}$ factors through this, the kernel of $A_n\to Z_{n-1}(A)$ is also $Z_{n}(A)$. Consider the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> B_n(A) @>>> A_n @>>> A_n/B_n(A) @>>> 0 \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> 0 @>>> Z_{n-1}(A)@>>> Z_{n-1}(A)@>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
of short exact sequences. By the snake lemma, we get an exact sequence of which the beginning looks like
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> B_n(A) @>>> Z_n(A) @>>> \mathrm{ker}(A_n/B_n(A)\to Z_{n-1}(A)) @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
$$
Therefore, $\mathrm{ker}(A_n/B_n(A)\to Z_{n-1}(A))\cong H_n(A)$.